# Cross Domain Request w/ Cors

Tags: c#, ember.js, asp.net-web-api, cors, cross-domain

I've got an ember solution, which locally runs on http://localhost:4200.  It request data from my WebApi Application, which utilizes Windows Authentication.  That currently runs on http://localhost:11470.  For some bizarre reason when my WebApi application responds it leaves off content such as: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.  Thus throwing the following exception:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:11470/api/Authentication/logins. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

If I look at the request, I clearly see the WebApi application isn't including such data in the header.  How can I correct my issue?

```
// Inside: 'WebApiConfig'
configuration.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:4200", "*", "*") { SupportsCredentials = true });

// Controller:
[Route("api/Authentication/Logins")]
public IHttpActionResult Login()
{
     if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
          return Ok();      

     return Unauthorized();
}

// Ember Ajax:
Ember.$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: 'http://localhost:11470/api/Authentication/logins',
     crossDomain: true,
     headers:{
          'Authorization': 'WWW-authenticate'
     },
     xhrFields: {
          withCredentials: true
     },
     error: function() { console.log('Error'); },
     success: function() { console.log('Working?'); }
});
```

I even tried the following:

- Forcing the header information in the `web.config`.
- Custom implementation of `IHttpActionResult`
- Custom filter implementation for `ActionFilterAttribute`.

Those don't hit before the console errors.  All that is enabled for the WebApi Application is Windows Authentication, if I navigate directly to localhost:11470/api/authentication/login it prompts me for my Active Directory credentials, then correctly responds.

I've read several documents, such as:

- http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532203.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

I can't get a solution to reliably work, what am I missing or not understanding?  I know it requires the header, but why is the Cors library for WebApi not sending it?

Comment: Why don't you use the `--proxy` from ember-cli in development, because in production you want to host your ember application in the same IIS as your asp.NET application anyways?

Comment: That still causes the same error, yes you're right I could run both within the same IIS Application Pool and instance.  But I'd like to understand why I encounter this.

Comment: can you provide more info about the request / response headers while making the AJAX call , may be using a tool like fiddler

Comment: Basically your request header should have 
Origin:  http://localhost:4200
and response header should have Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200 or *

Comment: @CleanCrispCode Yes I can, I know I need the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` but for some odd reason my WebApi isn't sending it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the exact same issue using the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors package.

Some things to try checking in the Web API (some you mentioned you tried, but I'm listing them with the details in which I tried anyway incase there is a difference in specifics):

1. If your API us using login information you need to allow CORS to send "Authentication" headers via the SupportsCendentials property, which *should* be enabled with something like:

   config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:4200", "*", "*") {
               SupportsCredentials = true
           });

However this solution didn't actually work for me, it didn't set the CORS header on my /token OPTIONS pre-flight, but it could be a version difference with the library or WebAPI version.

2. In your Web.config check if you're disabling the OPTIONS handler (i think this is a default behavior), which is what the pre-flight is trying to call:

under system.webServer.handlers:

```
<!--<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />--> <!--Allow options handling (preflight requests) by removing this line-->
```

3. Force it: Under system.webServer.httpProtocol add all of these for your custom headers to force them through (disabling the other CORS options if you try this).

```xml
<customHeaders>
    <!--Enable CORS for all requests (TODO Fix this, move to OWIN settings) -->
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, Content-Type, Authorization" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE" />
  </customHeaders>
```

Those changes allowed my API to respond with the correct headers, and I would recommend starting there.

4. Instead of using the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors CORS package and setting it in the WebApiConfig.cs you could set it directly on the OWIN middlewhere in Startup.cs or the Startup.Auth.cs, and as the **FIRST** line in either of these, before any other OWIN pineline, add:

   app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

Answer (score 1):

add Packages

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <packages>
   <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
   <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
   <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
   <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
   <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net461" />
 </packages>


public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
         {
             config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

             //config.EnableCors();
             var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");

             config.EnableCors(cors);
             config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                 name: "DefaultApi",
                 routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
}
```

JQuery

```
url: ApiPath + "/api/Orders/OrderNumber/" + orderNo,
         dataType: "json",
         crossDomain: true,
         headers: { "__RequestVerificationToken": AntiForgery.getToken() },
         //headers: { "__RequestVerificationToken": AntiForgery.getToken() },
         success: function (data) {
             $.each(data.ItemList, function (key, value) {
                 SettingArrayLists(value);
}}}}
```